# Child theme directory in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, content-management-system

I am new in making child theme in wordpress, i have a problem about my childtheme. How can i change the footer.php in child theme if it was being placed in other directory in my parent theme. Here it is, the parent theme puts the footer.php under hooks->footer.php
Parent Theme footer directory :
[image: Parent theme directory]

Here is my child theme where i want to change the footer 
the directory of my child theme ? :
[image: Child theme directory]

here is my child theme functions.php :

```
<?php
//
// Recommended way to include parent theme styles.
//  (Please see http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#How_to_Create_a_Child_Theme)
//  
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array('parent-style')
    );
}
//
// Your code goes below
//
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct method for binding Parent and child theme is using wp_enqueue_scripts action and use wp_enqueue_style() in your child theme’s functions.php as shown below.

```
    <?php
    function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

       $parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for     the Twenty Thirteen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

Check More details in http://www.codextutor.com/creating-child-theme-in-wordpress/

Hope it will help you.